# Pure CSS Parallax Scrolling (Keith Clark ) issue using Chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, parallax

I'm working on a project and trying to use Keith Clark's Pure CSS Parallax Scrolling technique. (http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) I'm finding that right now (October 2016) it doesn't seem to be working in the current version of Chrome. (It works on an older version and on Safari.) This Codepen of Keith's shows the technique: http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw/

When I view that Codepen with Chrome, the "background" images in his #slide1:before and #slide3:before pseudo elements are misaligned.

Can you confirm that it is currently not working in Chrome? Can anyone suggest how to fix this so that it works in the current version of Chrome?

I've tried applying all of the Chrome-related "fixes" that he suggests, without success, but perhaps I am just applying them to the wrong elements? I've searched for discussions about Chrome problems regarding this technique but am not finding any answers. This question might have been about the same issue, but was never answered: [Why does not (Pure CSS) Parallax Scrolling work properly in Chrome? (Slide #2 background bugs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416462/why-does-not-pure-css-parallax-scrolling-work-properly-in-chrome-slide-2-ba) I hope my question is more specific!

Here is the code from that Codepen:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="slide header" id="title">
  <h1>Pure CSS Parallax</h1>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide1">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide2">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/"> 
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide3">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide header" id="slide4">
    <h1>The End</h1>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

img:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#title {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/");
   background-attachment: fixed;  
}

#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/5/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}

#slide4 {
  background: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `transform-style: inhert;` from the `.slide` class: :)

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
```

}